# Google Cloud: Auto-deploy static files from Source Repository to Cloud Storage

Tags: automation, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, static-files, google-cloud-source-repos

I am building a serverless web application with all the source code managed by Google's Cloud Source Repository. My directory looks like this:

```
/webapp
  /functions
    *serverless functions*
  /static
    /css
      app.css
    /js
      app.js
```

I have build triggers active on this repository monitoring the serverless functions and redeploying them as Google Cloud Functions every time a change is pushed, which is great. My problem now is that I can't seem to find a way to get my css and js automatically pushed into a Cloud Storage bucket for general availability in a likewise manner.

How is this generally done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify how you implemented your automated deployment but you may have used Cloud Build like shown in this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/testing#continuous_testing_and_deployment) on Cloud Functions continuous deployment.

Building on this, you can simply add a build step to deploy your static files to Cloud Storage using the [gsutil tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#uploading_your_sites_files). For example:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['functions', 'deploy', '[YOUR_DEPLOYED_FUNCTION_NAME]', '[YOUR_FUNCTION_TRIGGER]', '--runtime', '[YOUR_RUNTIME]', '--entry-point', '[YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME_IN_CODE]']
  dir: 'webapp/functions'
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args: ['rsync', '-R', 'webapp/static', 'gs://your_gcs_bucket/']
```

Comment: I was indeed using cloudbuild with gcloud, no idea there was a gsutil variant of it. Thanks!